# Angular showing first element of array by default in div before selection

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular

I'm trying to show the first element returned of the list before the user do a selection on the button. For now when you land for first time in the page nothing is selected but I want the first object is selected by defaut.
My HTML is :

```
<div class="details">
<div class="selector">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let destination of destinations">
      <button
        type="button"
        [class.active]="destination == selectedDestination"
        (click)="onSelect(destination)"
      >
        {{ destination.name }}
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div><div class="detailsSelected" *ngIf="selectedDestination">
  <h1>{{ selectedDestination.name }}</h1>
  <p class="desription">
    {{ selectedDestination.description }}
  </p>
</div>
```

and the TS is:

```
export class DestinationComponent implements OnInit {

destinations: Destinations[] = [];
  constructor(private destinationsService: DestinationsService) {}
  getDestinations(): void {
    this.destinationsService
      .getDestinations()
      .subscribe((destinations) => (this.destinations = destinations));
  }
  selectedDestination = this.destinations[0];
  onSelect(destination: Destinations): void {
    this.selectedDestination = destination;
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getDestinations();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just assign it when you get the data

```
getDestinations(): void {
    this.destinationsService
      .getDestinations()
      .subscribe((destinations) => {
        this.destinations = destinations;
        this.selectedDestination = destinations[0];
      })
}
```